# Reload UITableView Data (Find indexPathForRow in dictionary)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am a newbie practising Objective-C to develop iOS apps. Last 2 line in the "handleRefresh" does not seem to work because I can not find the indexPathForRow for the new date and pass it to the UITableView and I can not put the new date in the dictionaryOfNumbers. Can you help me?

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  deleteTableView
//
//  Created by Mehmetcan Oralalp on 25/11/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Mehmetcan Oralalp. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NumbersCellIdentifier";

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableViewNumbers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOfNumbers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *barButtonAction;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allTimes;
@end

static NSString *SectionOddNumbers = @"Odd Numbers";
static NSString *SectionEvenNumbers = @"Even Numbers";

static NSString *SectionDynamicDate = @"Dynamic Date";

@implementation ViewController

//use refresh
- (void) handleRefresh:(id)paramSender{
    /* Put a bit of delay between when the refresh control is released
      and when we actually do the refreshing to make the UI look a bit
      smoother than just doing the update without the animation */
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 1.0f;
    dispatch_time_t popTime =
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        /* Add the current date to the list of dates that we have
         so that when the table view is refreshed, a new item will appear
         on the screen so that the user will see the difference between
         the before and the after of the refresh */
        [self.allTimes addObject:[NSDate date]];

        //PROBLEM IS HERE!!!
        NSIndexPath *indexPathOfNewRow =
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];
        [self.tableViewNumbers insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfNewRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    });
}
//refresh ends here


- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *sectionNameInDictionary =
    self.dictionaryOfNumbers.allKeys[indexPath.section];

    NSArray *sectionArray = self.dictionaryOfNumbers[sectionNameInDictionary];

    NSNumber *number = sectionArray[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           number];

    return cell;

}

- (NSMutableDictionary *) dictionaryOfNumbers{

    if (_dictionaryOfNumbers == nil){
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfEvenNumbers =
        [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[
                                                @0,
                                                @2,
                                                @4,
                                                @6,
                                                ]];

        NSMutableArray *arrayOfOddNumbers =
        [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[
                                                @1,
                                                @3,
                                                @5,
                                                @7,
                                                ]];

        self.allTimes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSDate date]];
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.allTimes];
        _dictionaryOfNumbers =
        [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
         initWithDictionary:@{
                              SectionDynamicDate : arrayOfDate,
                              SectionEvenNumbers : arrayOfEvenNumbers,
                              SectionOddNumbers : arrayOfOddNumbers,
                              }];

    }
    return _dictionaryOfNumbers;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.barButtonAction =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithTitle:@"Delete Odd Numbers"
     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
     target:self
     action:@selector(deleteOddNumbersSection:)];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.barButtonAction
                                      animated:NO];

    self.tableViewNumbers = [[UITableView alloc]
                             initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                             style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [self.tableViewNumbers registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
                  forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    self.tableViewNumbers.autoresizingMask =
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    self.tableViewNumbers.delegate = self;
    self.tableViewNumbers.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableViewNumbers];

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(handleRefresh:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableViewNumbers addSubview:self.refreshControl];

}

@end
```

Comment: Don't just spam your question with an entire class. Narrow it down to just the relevant parts. Point out the exact place in the code you are having problems with.

Comment: I organised it and left the related functions only. Hope this helps you to help me.

Comment: `didReceiveMemoryWarning` pretty much unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you use a *dictionary* as data source for the
table view. The key/values pairs in a dictionary do not have a defined order.

You should use an *array* instead, which could initially look like:

```
NSArray *dataSource = @[
                        @{@"title": @"Dynamic Date",
                          @"rows" : [ @[[NSDate date]] mutableCopy] },
                        @{@"title": @"Even Numbers",
                          @"rows" : [ @[@0, @2, @4] mutableCopy] },
                        @{@"title": @"Odd Numbers",
                          @"rows" : [ @[@1, @3, @5] mutableCopy] },
                        ];
```

This simplifies all data source method considerably. For example,

```
NSString *title = dataSource[section][@"title"];
```

is the title for a section, and

```
NSString *item = dataSource[indexPath.section][@"rows"][indexPath.row];
```

is the item at a given index path.

And if you insert a new item (e.g. another date)
into one of the "rows" arrays, you know exactly where it will appear in the
table view. For example, to add another date in section 0:

```
NSMutableArray *dates = dataSource[0][@"rows"];
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfNewRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[dates count] inSection:0];
[dates addObject:[NSDate date]];
[self.tableViewNumbers insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfNewRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```